# Adding time value into network model of ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, time

I am trying to set up a network model in ArcGis 10.3.1 so that I can find a route which will also give the time in minutes. The tutorial guide says this is set  up in the attributes of the network dataset, but within this stage there are various evaluators and I am not sure which one to use. In the attribute table of the feature class I am using I do have a length and time field already calculated.

How to incorporate time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add cost evaluator, called `Minutes`
2. Usage_Type `Cost`
3. Units `Minutes`
4. Build the route network
5. Create a new route
6. Use the `Minutes evaluator` as `Impendance` in the route properties

[image: Cost evaluator]

[image: Route options]